# Sql server setup fails : Oops ther was an error while checking the rules of sql server setup

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have been attempting to install SQL Server 2016 Express, on my computer, However it keeps failing, and it's not giving me an error message this text written below just keeps popping up and than the installer only gives me the option to close it.

Oops...

There was an error while checking Rules of Sql Server setup.

This happens every time I try to do the basic install, so I tried the custom, all it did was download the files than shut off the installer and just shuts off if I choose the option now.

I am the Admin account of my computer and there is only this account and the guest account. The only indication of the problem is the text and there is no Error Message or Number to accompany it and every time I've tried to google it none of the articles mention the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uninstalled all stuff about SQL from Programs and Features.
And then deleted %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\ folder.
Then Sql Express 2017 setup ran correctly.

[For more information:](https://www.ryadel.com/en/sql-server-2017-setup-install-error-oops-language-not-supported-rules-fix/)

Comment: This helped me out. I removed SqlExpress, but the uninstall took forever. I had just to exit it before finishing and I got stuck not being able to install Sql Express 2019  again.
You should probably delete files within the mentioned folder after uninstalling it first, as deleting might corrupt registry or setup .. perhaps..

Answer (score 2):

Execute the next command from admin cmd:

```
mofcomp C:\Windows\System32\WBEM\cimwin32.mof
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and am recording this here in case anyone else needs the information.

Before doing anything drastic, make sure you ran the setup as Administrator (it's not enough to *be* the administrator of the machine, you  have to right click on the .exe and 'Run as Administrator').

The next error I encountered was the installer telling me to restart my machine.

I also found that an existing SQL Native Client 2012 will cause the installation to fail. I uninstalled it as described here

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/an-installation-package-for-the-product-microsoft-sql-server-2012-native-client-cannot-be-found-during-sql-server-2017-install

and reinstalled. This time the installation completed successfully.